# How do I detect whether a mongodb serializer is already registered?

Tags: mongodb

I have created a custom serializer for mongoDB.
I can register it and it works as expected.

However the my application sometimes throws an error because it tries to register the serializer twice.

How do I detect whether a serializer has already been registered and thus stop my application from registering a second time?

Comment: What programming language are you using? MongoDB has drivers for a ton of languages... Also, it would be very helpful if you provided snippets of the code that register the serializer and the serializer itself. Apart from that, the answer is probably: call the registration only once in some kind of global startup method.

Comment: I'm using the C# driver. The code I'm using to register is 'BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(typeof (Type), typeSerializer);'. However there is no method on the BsonSerializer to check weather the type is already registerd

Answer (score 4):

If you are using

```
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(typeof (Type), typeSerializer);
```

you might get this error "there is already a serializer registered for type". Because you cannot register the same type of serializer 2 times. But you can write your own serializer and this serializer will work before default serializers.

For instance: if you want to use local `DateTime` instead of Utc which is default.

all you need to do is that writing a class implementing `IBsonSerializationProvider`and register this provider to `BsonSerializer` **as soon as possible**!

here is the sample code.

```
public class LocalDateTimeSerializationProvider : IBsonSerializationProvider
{
    public IBsonSerializer GetSerializer(Type type)
    {
        return type == typeof(DateTime) ? DateTimeSerializer.LocalInstance : null;
    }
}
```

and to be able to register

```
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializationProvider(new LocalDateTimeSerializationProvider());
```

I hope this helps, you can also read the original documentation in [here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/reference/bson/serialization/#serializer-registry)
this .net driver version of mongodb is 2.4!

Comment: Definitely helps.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:** Ig you are lazy, use `BsonSerializer.LookupSerializer` or `BsonMemberMap.GetSerializer`. To **do it right**, *make sure the registration code is called once and only once*.

The best approach to avoid this is to make sure the serializer is registered only once. It's a good idea to have some global startup code that registers anything that is global to the application once, and only once. That includes stuff like dependency injector configuration, tools like automapper and the mongodb driver. If you call this code only once and from a single point in code, you don't need to worry about thread safety, dead locks or similar troubles.

The MongoDB driver configuration settings are thread-safe, but don't assume that this is true for all software packages that you might need to configure. Also, locking can be **very expensive** performance wise if your code is multi-threaded, for instance in a web-application. Last but not least, that lookup you're doing might not be trivial in the first place, because some methods need to walk an entire inheritance tree.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Yes I agree that its best to have the registration done only once. The issue we have is that we have a lot of integration tests written which we run concurrently, thus we can't run the registration code run only once without changing the structure of quite a few tests. That's why a check helps. When I use the LookupSerializer method, I get an IBsonSerializer, I'm still not sure however how to determine if its registered. Can you help?

Comment: Either compare the result to the serializer you registered, i.e. `if(LookupSerializer() == typeSerializerInstance)` or use reflection by calling `GetType()` on the returned instance of `IBsonSerializer`. The former will probably come with the same problem as doing the registration only once, so you'll probably have to resort to the second option. Keep in mind that without a lock, there's still a chance for this to go wrong, i.e. while thread 2 calls `GetType()`, thread 1 calls `RegisterSerializer` and it goes boom...

Comment: This might not be applicable for everyone, but I was able to use a static constructor to ensure my serializer registration happened only once for the entire process.

Answer (score 1):

Ensuring this is only run once is obviously the desired goal but in circumstances where this is not possible i.e. in my case, integration tests where I was creating the host builder for each fixture, you can use the TryRegisterSerializer method instead which will swallow the error:

`BsonSerializer.TryRegisterSerializer(typeof (Type),objectSerializer);`